# Moving a button in the middle of an SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

What would be the best way to move a playbutton in the middle of an SVG?
Is there anyone who can help me do this?

All the code is provided below. It's telling me to add more details, but that's about it. I put all the code below.

https://jsfiddle.net/cy8v6657/1/

```html
    <svg width="238" height="238" viewBox="0 0 238 238">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="238" height="238" fill="blue" />
      <rect x="7" y="7" width="224" height="224" fill="black" />
      <rect x="14" y="14" width="210" height="210" fill="red" />
      <rect x="21" y="21" width="196" height="196" fill="black" />
      <rect x="28" y="28" width="182" height="182" fill="yellow" />
      <rect x="35" y="35" width="168" height="168" fill="black" />
      <rect x="42" y="42" width="154" height="154" fill="orange" />
      <rect x="49" y="49" width="140" height="140" fill="black" />
      <rect x="56" y="56" width="126" height="126" fill="lime" />
      <rect x="63" y="63" width="112" height="112" fill="black" />
      <rect x="70" y="70" width="98" height="98" fill="teal" />
      <rect x="77" y="77" width="84" height="84" fill="black" />
      <rect x="84" y="84" width="70" height="70" fill="silver" />
      <rect x="91" y="91" width="56" height="56" fill="black" />
      <rect x="98" y="98" width="42" height="42" fill="#1155cc" />
      <rect x="105" y="105" width="28" height="28" fill="black" />
      <rect x="112" y="112" width="14" height="14" fill="gold" />
    </svg>
    
    
    
    <button id="playButton2" style="width:50px; height:50px; border:none; cursor: pointer; background-color:transparent; background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/A445IfJ.png')" onclick=" 
    var player = document.getElementById('player');
    player.volume=1.0; 
    var button = document.getElementById('playButton2');
    if (player.paused) {
        playButton2.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\'https://i.imgur.com/qg4rg7Z.png\')';
        player.play();
      } else {
        playButton2.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\'https://i.imgur.com/A445IfJ.png\')';
        player.pause();
      }">
     </button>
    
    <audio id="player" preload="none" style="display:none;">
    <source src='' type='audio/mpeg'/>
    </audio>
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39918119/7088500.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Place both - your svg and your button, inside a wrapper div.
2. Give position `relative` to this wrapper div.
3. Center the button using absolute positioning inside the wrapper div.

```css
#svg-wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 238px;
  height: 238px;
}
#svg-wrapper #playButton2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="svg-wrapper">
<svg width="238" height="238" viewBox="0 0 238 238">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="238" height="238" fill="blue" />
      <rect x="7" y="7" width="224" height="224" fill="black" />
      <rect x="14" y="14" width="210" height="210" fill="red" />
      <rect x="21" y="21" width="196" height="196" fill="black" />
      <rect x="28" y="28" width="182" height="182" fill="yellow" />
      <rect x="35" y="35" width="168" height="168" fill="black" />
      <rect x="42" y="42" width="154" height="154" fill="orange" />
      <rect x="49" y="49" width="140" height="140" fill="black" />
      <rect x="56" y="56" width="126" height="126" fill="lime" />
      <rect x="63" y="63" width="112" height="112" fill="black" />
      <rect x="70" y="70" width="98" height="98" fill="teal" />
      <rect x="77" y="77" width="84" height="84" fill="black" />
      <rect x="84" y="84" width="70" height="70" fill="silver" />
      <rect x="91" y="91" width="56" height="56" fill="black" />
      <rect x="98" y="98" width="42" height="42" fill="#1155cc" />
      <rect x="105" y="105" width="28" height="28" fill="black" />
      <rect x="112" y="112" width="14" height="14" fill="gold" />
    </svg>
    
    
    
    <button id="playButton2" style="width:50px; height:50px; border:none; cursor: pointer; background-color:transparent; background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/A445IfJ.png')" onclick=" 
    var player = document.getElementById('player');
    player.volume=1.0; 
    var button = document.getElementById('playButton2');
    if (player.paused) {
        playButton2.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\'https://i.imgur.com/qg4rg7Z.png\')';
        player.play();
      } else {
        playButton2.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\'https://i.imgur.com/A445IfJ.png\')';
        player.pause();
      }">
     </button>
   </div><!--#svg-wrapper-->
    
    <audio id="player" preload="none" style="display:none;">
    <source src='' type='audio/mpeg'/>
    </audio>
```

**Update**
If you cannot use external stylesheet for some reason as you mentioned in comments, you can use the same styles inline.

Change following lines:

```
<div id="svg-wrapper" style="position: relative;width: 238px;height: 238px;">

<button id="playButton2" style="position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);width:50px; height:50px; border:none; cursor: pointer; background-color:transparent; background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/A445IfJ.png')" onclick=" 
    var player = document.getElementById('player');
    player.volume=1.0; 
    var button = document.getElementById('playButton2');
    if (player.paused) {
        playButton2.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\'https://i.imgur.com/qg4rg7Z.png\')';
        player.play();
      } else {
        playButton2.style.backgroundImage = 'url(\'https://i.imgur.com/A445IfJ.png\')';
        player.pause();
      }">
     </button>
```

Comment: Is there an HTML way to do that?

Comment: html way means? without using css?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Is there any restriction regarding the use off css. If you prefer so, you can add the css rules inline as you have done for your `#playButton2` element.

Comment: I don't think I'm doing it correctly, can you show me please?

Comment: @svgcoding I have added updated code. Please check if this is what you need.

Comment: I put that in and it doesn't look like it's working, unless I'm doing something wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/cy8v6657/6/

Comment: @svgcoding  you just need to move the opening `#svg-wrapper` tag before the `svg`. Check here https://jsfiddle.net/cy8v6657/10/